# Is it possible to output SmtpClient.SendAsync() result to a MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, callback, smtpclient, sendasync

Is there a way to display an SmtpClient.SendAsync() method result (success or failure) on an MVC view from a call back function?

Comment: how are you calling ? from  client (js) or normal form submit event ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [MVC Mailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). It allows for the creation of emails with razor views, and also has an async option.